# Can dielectric coated metal wire mesh in electrolyte be a capacitor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-circuits, electric-fields

Since capacitance is proportional to the area of the plates, why don't we just make a mesh out of metal wire (plate #1) and coat it with a thin layer of dielectric material, then submerge this mesh into an electrolyte (plate #2) which is connected to one not-submerged, not coated end of the wire mesh? All that crazy big surface area would serve as the plates area!

Seems too simple to be true... most things are these days :')